# Trying to add the result of a users input into string

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm very new to python and just messing around trying to have a user input a few things then have the ouput of

> 'Your name is x you are x years old and you work as a x!'

However I can only get it to come out as

> Your name is None, You are None years old and you work as a None!

This is the code I have

```
myName = print(input('Please enter your name: '))
myAge = print(input('Please enter your age: '))
myJob = print(input('Please enter your job: '))

print('Your name is {0}, You are {1} years old and you work as a {2}!'.format(myName, myAge, myJob))
```

Any Help is really appreciated.

Comment: remove `print` in your code, it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use print(), because print() doesn't return a value, it only outputs a string in the console:

```
myName = input('Please enter your name: ')
myAge = input('Please enter your age: ')
myJob = input('Please enter your job: ')

print('Your name is {0}, You are {1} years old and you work as a {2}!'.format(myName, 
myAge, myJob))
```

Comment: Amazing thanks that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```py
myName = print(input('Please enter your name: '))
```

`print()` is unecessary here.

```py
myName = input('Please enter your name: ')

print('Your name is {}, You are {} years old and you work as a {}!'.format(myName, myAge, myJob))
```

should work.